# Calculate set difference using jinja2 (in ansible)

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have two lists of strings in my ansible playbook, and I'm trying to find the elements in list A that aren't in list B - a set difference. However, I don't seem to be able to access the python `set` data structure. Here's what I was trying to do:

```
- set_fact:
    difference: "{{ (set(listA) - set(listB)).pop() }}"
```

But I get an error saying `'set' is undefined`. Makes sense to me since it's not a variable but I don't know what else to do. How can I calculate the set difference of these two lists? Is it impossible with the stock jinja functionality in ansible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out there is a [built-in filter for this in ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) (not in generic jinja) called `difference`.

This accomplishes what I was trying to do in my question:

```
"{{ (listA | difference(listB)) | first }}"
```

Comment: Is there a way to find the difference between two lists without knowing which of the two is the largest ?

Comment: @KostasDemiris that would be a great standalone question.

Comment: True, but thankfully I found it. {{ listX | symmetric_difference(listY) }}

Comment: @KostasDemiris symmetric difference is not the same as the difference between two lists. If one set is not a subset of the other, then the order of operands matters with set difference, whereas with symmetric difference it does not matter, because they will give different results. For example: `[1,2] | difference([2,3])` is `[1]`, but `[1,2] | symmetric_difference([2,3])` is `[1,3]`. If you reverse the operands, `[2,3] | difference([1,2])` is `[3]`, but `[2,3] | symmetric_difference([1,2])` is still `[1,3]`. So, be careful!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. difference is sketchy, but symmetric_difference is what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

In generic Jinja2, this can be achieved quite easily, combining the [`reject`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#reject) filter with the [`in`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#in) test:

```
"{{ listA | reject('in', listB) | first }}"
```

This requires Jinja >= [2.10](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/releases/tag/2.10)